# How to get sent and received messages in a correct order in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a chat app using Laravel, and I need help with sorting the messages correctly.

My current implementation works, but it retrieves all messages sent by the current user to anyone, as well as messages sent to the current user by anyone.

I want it to only retrieve messages between the current user and the user they are chatting with.

I have two tables for messages: Chats which stores sender and recipient IDs, and Messages which stores message contents. Please see the attached image for the table structures.

I have included code snippets to show the relationships between the Users, Chats, and Messages models.

Can anyone help me with this issue please?

**Users Model**

```
public function chats() 
{
        return $this->hasMany(Chat::class, 'recipient_id')
        ->orWhere(function($query) {
            $query->where('sender_id', '<>', $this->id)
            ->where('recipient_id', $this->id);
        })
        ->orWhere(function($query) {
            $query->where('sender_id', $this->id)
            ->where('recipient_id', '<>', $this->id);
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'asc');
}
```

**Chats Model**

```
public function users() 
{
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function messages()
{
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'chat_id');
}
```

**Messages model**

```
public function chats()
{
        return $this->belongsTo(Chat::class, 'chat_id');
}
```

**Messages Controller**

```
public function getMessages($username) {
        $host = User::where('username', $username)->first();
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($username !== $user->username && !Abilities::isBlocked($username) && Abilities::canBlock($username)) {
            $messages = $host->chats()
            ->with(['messages' => function ($query) {
                $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
            }])
            ->where('recipient_id', $user->id)
            ->get()
            ->each(function($chat) {
                $chat->status = $chat->sender_id === Auth::user()->id ? "sent" : "received";
            });
            
            return response()->json([
                "messages" => $messages,
            ]);
        }
        
        return response()->json(["messages" => "Unauthorized access."]);
}
```

**Tables Structure**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relations are all correctly set up this should get you all chats between given users. (Assumes it's possible for two users to have *multiple* chats. If not this should return the first `Chat` model only.

```php
public function getDiscussionWith(int $userOneId, int $userTwoId): Collection
{
    return Chat::query()
        ->with('messages')
        // messages where One is the sender and Two is the receiver
        ->where(function(EloquentBuilder $query) use ($userOneId, $userTwoId){
            $query->where('sender_id', $userOneId)
                ->where('receiver_id', $userTwoId);
        })
        // or where One is the receiver and Two is the sender
        ->orWhere(function(EloquentBuilder $query) use ($userOneId, $userTwoId){
            $query->where('sender_id', $userTwoId)
                ->where('receiver_id', $userOneId);
        })
        ->get();
}
```

Called like

```php
$discussions = $chatRepository->getDiscussionsWith($user->id, $host->id);

foreach($discussions as $discussion){
    $messages = $discussion->messages->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```